# Turning a workspace in Linux desktop into a permanent terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, archlinux, kde-plasma

I have Manjaro Linux on my laptop with KDE desktop. In desktop environments you can have multiple desktops. I want to turn one of these desktops into a permanent terminal. A complete full-screen terminal like the one you get when you don't have a desktop environment installed. Is there anyway to turn one of my workspaces in KDE into a permanent terminal ??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using a plasmoid? It's not complete full screen but it's as near as it gets.
For example [this](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=108120) or [this](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=142753).
Also, have you tried Yakuake? It's not located on the desktop, but invoked by a key press (usually F12) or by the mouse reaching the top border if you want. It's the first program I install on any KDE setup, it's vital to my workflow.

Comment: Better then nothing, thank you